# retrieve text in the div tag with lxml in python

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, lxml

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
<span class="label">Source:</span>
08/09/2013
</div>
<div class="row">
<span class="label">Last revised:</span>
08/09/2013
</div>
```

I want to retrieve the release date and last revised date, using code like this:

```
url="http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2013-4031&cid=2"
html=urllib.urlopen(url)
parser=etree.HTMLParser()
tree=etree.parse(html,parser)
root=tree.getroot()

for div in tree.iter('div'):
 title=div.xpath('.//child::*')
 if( title[0].text=="Source:"):
  print (#release date#)
```

I tried print div.text, but in doesn't work. How can I do this?
I use python 2.7 and lxml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `tail` of the `span` element and not the text of the `div`.

```
for div in tree.iter('div'):
    title = div.xpath('.//child::*')
    if title[0].text == 'Source:':
        print(title[0].tail.strip())
```

Comment: I also tried this:
div[0].tail.strip()  and it has the same result as title[0].tail !!
why??

Comment: Because iterating through an element is like iterating through it's child elements, and the `span` is is the first child of `div`, so you can index it with `[0]`